# Why does µ appear to be a valid variable name in Java but not in Groovy?

Tags: java, variables, groovy

If I try `µ = new Object()` in Groovy code I see this:

```
ideaGroovyConsole.groovy: 1: unexpected char: 0xB5 @ line 1, column 1.
   µ = new Object()
```

whereas `Object µ = new Object();` is fine in Java.

`π` is a perfectly valid variable name in both places. Why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OP: *This answer is essentially correct. See note at end for more details.*]

The character μ is valid but the character µ is not.

See the code at https://github.com/jeffbrown/micro/blob/76a81f9c511f6eb1d1f30230e8e5ace878f2e6ee/src/main/groovy/micro/MicroDemo.groovy#L6-L8.

```
package micro

class MicroDemo {
    static void main(args) {

        String μ = 'Jeff Scott Brown'

        println "The Name Is ${μ}"
    }
}
```

If you clone that repo and run `./gradlew run` you will see the following output:

```
The Name Is Jeff Scott Brown
```

---

*Note added by OP:*

The basic problem I'm seeing is that the Mac keyboard is inputting µ (which happens to be U+B5, the "micro" symbol), which Groovy correctly rejects as a variable name (as it is not a letter character), whereas the Java compiler *does* accept this as a variable name (though arguably it shouldn't).

Both Java and Groovy accept μ (U+3BC, the greek *letter* mu) correctly, though this is (peculiarly) obscured by my IDE (IntelliJ) which:

- doesn't complain about "micro" in the Groovy code
- will not accept unicode escapes like `\u00b5` and `\u03bc` in the source code for Java *or* Groovy

though if you ignore the IDE and build/run anyway, they execute (or fail) as described.

Comment: Interesting.  I type the same character in IntelliJ in Java and in a Groovy shell (using an Apple keyboard ALT+m).  And yet you imply that I have input two different characters.  Is that really the case?  Is there some encoding obfuscation that is occurring?

Comment: @StevePowell "And yet you imply that I have input two different characters. Is that really the case?" - Yes.  See https://github.com/jeffbrown/micro/blob/417e48221d28c5e732b9f3f0a494d8bdb97d30b3/src/main/groovy/micro/MicroDemo.groovy#L11-L17

Comment: To clarify, I am not saying that you input two different characters.  I don't know what you did.  What I am saying is that there are 2 different characters.  One of them is a valid Groovy identifier and the other isn't.

Comment: Java is a separate language from Groovy.  The don't have the same compiler or same grammar.  We initially created the Groovy grammar based on the Java grammar, but they are not the same.  There are a lot of differences.

Comment: I don't think you should use either of those characters as identifiers.

Comment: Thanks. I have sorted out why it was confusing for me (and my experiments), and added that to your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two µs in Unicode; the Greek letter U+3BC and the physics unit prefix for micro, 10<sup>-6</sup> U+B5.

I could imagine that in Groovy the latter `µ` was forgotten, as the rule is that an identifier contains *letters* and some other symbols. You might try `\u03BC`.